Prove a sequence converges almost surely when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{Var}[X_n]}{n^2}=\infty$
Given a sequence of independent random variables $(X_n)$ with distribution
$$
\mathbb{P}[X_n = 2^n] = \frac{1}{2^n}, \quad \mathbb{P}[X_n = -1] = \mathbb{P}[X_n = 1] = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}},
$$
prove that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \xrightarrow{\text{almost surely}} 0.
$$
I calculated that $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 1, \mathbb{E}[X_n^2] = 1 + 2^n - \frac{1}{2^n}$, so $\mathrm{Var}[X_n] = 2^n - \frac{1}{2^n}$. Thus,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{Var}[X_n]}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n-\dfrac{1}{2^n}}{n^2} = \infty,
$$
and therefore, I cannot apply Kolmogorov's strong law of large numbers.

We'll use the following lemma, called Kronecker's lemma, in particular,

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n}$ exists, and finite. Then, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n x_n = 0$

To use this lemma, we'll first prove that
$$
    \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n}{n} \text{ converges a.s}
$$
This is just an application of Kolmogorov's Three Series theorem: Set $Y_k = \dfrac{X_k}{k}$ if $\vert X_k \vert \le k$ and $0$ otherwise. Then,
$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_k}{k} \neq Y_k\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X_k \vert > k) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} < \infty$$
Also, since $\mathbb{E}(Y_k) = 0$, we have $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(Y_k) = 0$. Finally,
$$
      \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \text{Var}(Y_k) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(Y_k^2) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2}\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{2^k}\right) \le \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} < \infty 
$$
Thus, $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n}{n}$ converges a.s. And by the Kronecker's lemma,
$$
    \left\{\omega: \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n(\omega)}{n} \text{ converges}\right\} \subseteq \left\{\omega: \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k(\omega) \text{ converges to } 0\right\}
$$

It helps to explain the sequence in words: With a steadily decreasing probability $2^{-n}$, $X_n$ is very high, $2^n$. Else, it is either one or minus one, with equal probability. This sequence thus has two dynamics: One that sometimes is very high, and some background noise that is always -1 or 1. Let' separate them.
Define $Y_n$ as sequence of independent random variables with $\mathbb P(Y_n=-1) = \mathbb P(Y_n=1)$ and $X_n$ now as $\mathbb P(X_n=2^n) = 2^{-n}$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=Y_n) = 1-2^{-n}$.
$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_n \to 0$ is now just the law of large numbers. What remains to prove is $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_n-Y_n) \to 0$.
Note that $X_n-Y_n$ is 0 with a growing probability. If you know the Borel-Cantelli lemma, you are already done. If not, consider the following: Fix some $N\in \mathbb N$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(\text{There exist some $n≥N$ where $X_n\ne Y_n$}) ≤ \sum_{n=N}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n\ne Y_n) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty 2^{-n} = 2^{-N+1}.
$$
But if there is no $n≥N$ with $X_n\ne Y_n$, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (X_n-Y_n)$ will only have a finite number of terms, and so
$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_n-Y_n) \to 0$ in this case.
Now if you let $N$ tend to infinity, you will see that the term goes to zero. So the probability of $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_n-Y_n) \to 0$ is 1.

I really like this explanation because it points at the heart of the issue. Am I reading this correctly that the non-zero values of $X_n$ could grow arbitrarily quickly with $n$ and the result would still apply (even though the convergence speed would be practically much slower)? For example: $X_n = \exp( \exp( \exp(n) ) )$ instead of $2^n$?

@GuillaumeDehaene yes, the "exception" values can be arbitrary, so long as there are a.s. only finitely many. The exception values would, however, affect whether the sequence converges in $L_1$. For instance, even the version in the problem doesn't converge in $L_1$, because the mean is $1$ for all finite $n$, but the mean of the $n \to \infty$ limit is $0$.

Nice answer. Maybe a link between $X_i$ and $Y_i$ could be stated, like $Y_i=X_i\mathbf{1}_{X_i\in{-1,1}}$.

@DavideGiraudo: in fact, such a link is even necessary, otherwise there’s no reason why one would have $X_i=Y_i$ for all large enough $i$ almost surely. In order to apply the law of large numbers, one would rather want $Y_i=X_i\mathbf{1}{|X_i| \leq 1}+Z_i\mathbf{1}{|X_i| > 1}$, where the $Z_i$ are iid from the $X_i$ and are $\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$ each.

@DavideGiraudo The link is there, $\mathbb P(X_n=Y_n) = 1-2^{-n}$. $Y_i$ is not $X_i$-measurable and vise versa, so a direct definition would require the use of a third variable, as in "Define $B_i$ to be independently unif${-1,1}$, then $Y_i = X_i \mathbf 1_{X_i\in{-1,1}} + B_i\mathbf 1_{X_i\notin {-1,1}}$.

@Aphelli Indeed, $X_i\mathbf{1}_{X_i\in {-1,1}}$ is not identically distributed but now we have the advantage that the variance does not explode (then we can conclude simply via Kolmogorov's maximal inequality and the Borel-Cantelli lemma). Yes it seems that we need to introduce new random variables if we really want to work with i.i.d.

Consider the indicator functions:
$$
{1}_{|X_n| > 1} = 
\begin{cases} 
1, & |X_n| > 1, \\
0, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\quad
{1}_{|X_n| \leq 1} = 
\begin{cases} 
1, & |X_n| \leq 1, \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Define $ Y_n = X_n \cdot {1}_{|X_n| > 1} $ and $ Z_n = Y_n \cdot {1}_{|X_n| \leq 1} $.
We have:
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \sum \mathbb{P}[|Y_n| > \varepsilon] = \sum \frac{1}{2^n} < \infty,
$$
which implies $ Y_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 0 $ and therefore:
$$
\frac{\sum Y_n}{n} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 0.
$$
Additionally, since $ \mathbb{E}[Z_n] = 0 $ and $ \mathrm{Var}[Z_n] = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} $, we obtain:
$$
\sum \frac{\mathrm{Var}[Z_n]}{n^2} = \sum \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum \frac{1}{n^2 2^n} < \infty.
$$
By the strong law of large numbers, it follows that:
$$
\frac{\sum Z_n}{n} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 0.
$$
Since $ X_n = Y_n + Z_n $, we conclude:
$$
\frac{\sum X_n}{n} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 0.
$$
Thus, the statement to be proved is established.
